# Problem when I want to filter on 3 conditions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, filtering

I have a question about filtering multiple conditions. I have a fully working code where I filter on two conditions with the filter function but when I want to add the third one is where it gets really difficult.

In the code snippet you can see the working code for two filter options. I only have to find a way to filter the days but that is really difficult.

Can someone help me with this issue, I'm really curious to see what a solution could be :)

```js
{
  const acts = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Men in coats",
      locatie: 1,
      day: 24,
      soort: "straatact"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Men in coats2",
      locatie: 4,
      day: 24,
      soort: "voorstelling"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Men in coats3",
      locatie: 4,
      day: 24,
      soort: "voorstelling"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Men in coats4",
      locatie: 2,
      day: 24,
      soort: "straatact"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Men in coats5",
      locatie: 5,
      day: 24,
      soort: "straatact"
    }
  ];

  let currentDay = `alle`;

  const init = () => {
    const $location = document.querySelector(`.locatie`);
    $location.addEventListener(`input`, handleInputLocation);

    const $soort = document.querySelector(`.soort`);
    $soort.addEventListener(`input`, handleInputSoort);

    const $days = document.querySelectorAll(`.option_day`);
    const daysArray = Array.from($days);
    daysArray.forEach(day => {
      day.addEventListener(`click`, handleClickDay);
    });
  };

  const handleClickDay = e => {
    const currentTarget = e.currentTarget;
    const currentValue = currentTarget.dataset.name;

    const $soort = document.querySelector(`.soort`);
    let soort = $soort.value;

    const $locatie = document.querySelector(`.locatie`);
    const locatie = $locatie.value;

    currentDay = currentValue;

    filterData(locatie, soort, currentValue);
  };

  const handleInputLocation = e => {
    const currentTarget = e.currentTarget;
    const currentValue = currentTarget.value;

    const $soort = document.querySelector(`.soort`);
    let soort = $soort.value;

    const dag = currentDay;

    filterData(currentValue, soort, dag);
  };

  const handleInputSoort = e => {
    const currentTarget = e.currentTarget;
    const currentValue = currentTarget.value;

    const $locatie = document.querySelector(`.locatie`);
    const locatie = $locatie.value;

    const dag = currentDay;

    filterData(locatie, currentValue, dag);
  };

  const filterData = (locatie, soort, dag) => {
let filteredActs = acts;

if (locatie !== "alle") {
  locatie = parseInt(locatie);
  filteredActs = filteredActs.filter(act => act.locatie === locatie);
}
if (soort !== "alle") {
  filteredActs = filteredActs.filter(act => act.soort === soort);
}
if (dag !== "alle") {
  filteredActs = filteredActs.filter(act => act.dag === parseInt(dag));
  console.log(parseInt(dag));
}
// …

console.log(filteredActs);
return filteredActs;
  };

  init();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <select class="select locatie">
      <option selected disabled value="alle">Location</option>
      <option value="alle">All</option>
      <option value="1">Location 1</option>
      <option value="2">Location 2</option>
      <option value="3">Location 3</option>
      <option value="4">Location 4</option>
      <option value="5">Location 5</option>
      <option value="6">Location 6</option>
    </select>
    <select class="select soort">
      <option selected disabled value="alle">Kind</option>
      <option value="alle">All</option>
      <option value="straatact">Straatacts</option>
      <option value="voorstelling">Voorstellingen</option>
    </select>
    <ul class="list_days">
      <li class="option_day" data-name="alle">All</li>
      <li class="option_day" data-name="24">Fr</li>
      <li class="option_day" data-name="25">Sa</li>
      <li class="option_day" data-name="26">Su</li>
    </ul>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are no limits on how many ways and times you can sort something, but you need to make sure you don't have problems with your conditional logic. For instance, do you have overlapping conditions, or are they mutually exclusive, etc. So, what are the three conditions you want to filter for, exactly?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see any problems with your code. What is not working as intended?

Comment: Well what I want is when I filter on days that this also pays attention to the already filtered location and kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overcomplicating it. Don't write multiple kinds of conditions, and select them on which *other* criteria are not selected. This indeed becomes unmanageable for many filtering criteria.

You can do either

```
function filterData = (…) => {
  let filteredActs = acts;
  if (locatie !== "alle") {
    locatie = parseInt(locatie);
    filteredActs = filteredActs .filter(act => act.locatie === locatie);
  }
  if (soort !== "alle") {
    filteredActs = filteredActs.filter(act => act.soort === soort);
  }
  // …
  return filteredActs;
}
```

or

```
function filterData = (…) => {
  return acts.filter(act =>
    (locatie === "alle" || act.locatie === parseInt(locatie)) &&
    (soort === "alle" || act.soort === soort)
    // && …
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that, it is a lot more readable, but now I have this problem where I cant filter on the number from the day so as follows the filteredActs is empty and it isn't possible to filter anymore after selecting a day, Ill update the code above so people can see what I understand. I really dont see the problem at all

Comment: Nevermind it perfectly works, it was a spelling error, @Bergi Your the man!